# Deciling by partitions in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table in Teradata which contains Sales Information per store pertaining to each region.

```
StoreID RegionID Sales
1        A       200
2        A       150
3        A       210
4        B       400
5        B       420
```

How can I find out the stores in top 2 deciles by sales for each region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `QUANTILE` function, but this is old [deprecated syntax](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_109A/ch09.13.128.html#ww711057). The top 2 decile are the top 20 percent and you can simply use `PERCENT_RANK` for this:

```
QUALIFY
   PERCENT_RANK()
   OVER (PARTITION BY RegionID
         ORDER BY Sales DESC) <= 0.2
```